# How do I hide hazelcast INFO logs?

Tags: logging, log4j, slf4j, hazelcast

I use Hazelcast in my application, and my console is flooded with Hazelcast logs. How do I "hide" all the info logs that I don't find so useful for the moment ?

In my application logging is made with slf4j with a log4j implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a logger with WARN level

```
<logger name="com.hazelcast" level="WARN" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="your_hz_file_appender" />
</logger>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure SLF4J to only show errors / warnings for the "com.hazelcast" package